# How do I trigger a change to a different audio channel via if/else using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Forgive me here, I'm very new to Python (and coding in general) but I'm honestly stumped.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is I'm attempting to trigger a change in music on this guessing game I'm working on, when someone gets the answer they get um... *rickrolled*.

The problem is that whenever I try to unpause the music or play the music once they guess correctly it won't work.

I've tried utilizing pygame.mixer.music.play(), pygame.mixer.music.pause(), etc... to no avail.

This is the the code...

```
# Adding rickroll Audio via pygame

import pygame

pygame.init()
main_channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
pause_channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
main_channel.play(pygame.mixer.Sound('quiztime.ogg'), loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)
pause_channel.play(pygame.mixer.Sound('rickroll.ogg'), loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)
pause_channel.pause()

# Secret Word
secret_word = 'rickroll'

# Created a 'guess' variable using the input statement

guess = input('Can you guess the secret word?: ')

# Added a guess count to implement hint system

guess_count = 0

# Condition using the While keyword

while guess != secret_word:
    guess_count += 1
    print('Almost... Try Again! ')
    guess = input('New Guess here plz: ')
    if guess_count == 3:
        print('Tis an old meme good friend...')
        guess = input('New Guess here plz: ')
    elif guess_count == 5:
        print('Think of a ginger man with soul~')
        guess = input('New Guess here plz: ')
    elif guess_count == 10:
        print("I wouldn't give you up ;)")
        guess = input('New Guess here plz: ')
    else:
        main_channel.pause()
        pause_channel.unpause()
        print("We're no strangers to loooooove~")
        # If done correctly should play rickroll upon correct guess.

print('Press ENTER to exit!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code a bit.

```py
# Adding rickroll Audio via pygame

import pygame

pygame.init()
main_channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
pause_channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
main_channel.play(pygame.mixer.Sound("quiztime.ogg"), loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)
pause_channel.play(pygame.mixer.Sound("rickroll.ogg"), loops=-1, fade_ms=5000)
pause_channel.pause()

# Secret Word
secret_word = "rickroll"

# Created a 'guess' variable using the input statement

guess = input("Can you guess the secret word?: ")

# Added a guess count to implement hint system

guess_count = 0

# Condition using the While keyword

while guess != secret_word:
    guess_count += 1
    print("Almost... Try Again! ")
    guess = input("New Guess here plz: ")
    if guess_count == 3:
        print("Tis an old meme good friend...")
        guess = input("New Guess here plz: ")
    elif guess_count == 5:
        print("Think of a ginger man with soul~")
        guess = input("New Guess here plz: ")
    elif guess_count == 10:
        print("I wouldn't give you up ;)")
        guess = input("New Guess here plz: ")

main_channel.pause()
pause_channel.unpause()
print("We're no strangers to loooooove~")

# If press enter exit, else
current_input = input("Press ENTER to exit!")
while current_input:
    current_input = input("Press ENTER to exit!")
```

### Explanation

- When `guess != secret_word` the loop works. So, if `guess` becomes the same as `secret_word`, the loop exits. Thus, we need to add the rickroll audio when guess matches. Your logic is correct, it will be just after the loop ends, which is the code that will be executed when loop exits.
- `current_input` takes in your next keystroke. If you press `Enter`, the value of `current_input` is `None`, which will help you exit this loop. Otherwise, you will continue getting rickrolled! :)

Do ask for any clarifications in case anything is unclear.